# How do I get this progress bar from react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile-development

[image]

[image: Whole Screen]
So I want to implement a progress bar like this in react native. I have found a library which is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-progress, but this library does not have a progress bar like this. The issue is the circle part. Is there a library which has a progress bar like this one? If there isn't, then any idea on how to implement this would be appreciated. So as a fellow commenter got confused whether it is a slider or progress bar, I will include the full screen image. There is a timer and the progress bar or progress slider reflects that in real time.

Comment: The image does not show a progress bar. This is a slider and a similar component is [implemented here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/slider).

Comment: I will explain a bit more. So, there is a timer which counts down from 0 to that number of seconds. This slider or progress bar reflects that status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can still exploit [react-native-community/slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/slider) for this purpose. This would make sense since we can allow the user to fast forward. If you do not want allow user interaction, you can still disable it via the slider component props.

For a smooth sliding, the slider changes its value at a higher tick rate. You might want to experiment with it a little bit to make it fit your needs.

Here is an example on how I did it.

```js
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(-1)

// takes time in seconds
function interpolate(time) {
  return time * 600
}

// runs 10 seconds, you can take any other value
const [time, setTime] = useState(interpolate(10))

useEffect(() => {
  if (progress < time && progress > -1) {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => setProgress(progress + 10), 10)
    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
  }
}, [progress, time])

const startTimer = React.useCallback(() => {
  setProgress(0)
}, [])

return (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ margin: 30 }}>
    <Slider
      style={{ width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: "red" }}
      value={progress}
      minimumValue={0}
      maximumValue={time}
      minimumTrackTintColor="#FFFFFF"
      maximumTrackTintColor="#FFFFFF"
    />
    <Pressable style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={() => startTimer()}>
      <Text>Toggle timer</Text>
    </Pressable>
  </SafeAreaView>
)
```

The above is a dummy implementation which will run a timer for 10 seconds and the slider will move automatically like a progress bar.

Comment: How do I pause it tho?

Comment: Add a state that guards this.

Comment: I tried to add a button which will set progress to -1 but that just moves the slider back to the initial position.

Comment: Yes, this is wrong. You can add a state, e.g. a simple boolean flag, which handles this. The progress state must be handled independently,

Comment: And will there be a prop which will pause it according to the flag?

Comment: And also, why are you multiplying the seconds by 600

Comment: Ok I get it. We can add a boolean flag in the if condition

Comment: Because the step size runs at a higher tick rate to make it seem like an animation or otherwise the slider will "jump" instead of sliding smoothly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244662/discussion-between-abhishek-and-david-scholz).